# Is there a way to ouput variables in a custom module?

Tags: nodes, users, hooks

I'm updating a custom module and I would like to output the $node and $user variable to see what is in it for a specific key.
The value of this key can be one or multiple strings and I'd like to know how it's made up because I need to look at certain user "roles" to see if the user can view the content or not.

I tried a var_dump and writing them in a file with file_put_contents but I don't see them showing up anywhere.

I'm a noob when it comes to php and it's pretty impossible for me to write this logic without knowing how to properly select the values of the keys in those variables.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: install devel module

Comment: The [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module is helpful for dumping vars to the screen. That's a good approach if you don't code much. However, even though it takes some overhead to get going initially, it's really worth setting up [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) with a nice code editor like PhpStorm (or some other IDE), if you're going to be doing any real amount of coding.

Comment: Xdebug is the best option IMO.  There was zero config for me when using DDev + PHPStorm.  I also use twig_tweak to output parameters passed to the template.
https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak

Comment: +1 for using Xdebug.